# import a test interface from a library's tests into application's tests

Tags: kotlin, junit5

I made a library. OrderedCollections. I import and use in an application. In the library is a junit5 test interface. I want to use the test interface in the application.

example, in library you have

```kotlin
interface BinaryTree<K:Comparable<K>,V> : Collection<Pair<K,V> {...}
```

in The tests for this library you have

```kotlin
interface TreeTests<K : Comparable<K>, V> {
    val tree: BinaryTree<K, V>
    @Test
    fun sorted() {
        val list = tree.toList().sortedBy { it.first }
        assertIterableEquals(list, tree)
    } 
}
```

I made an implementation in the application of BinaryTree, but it is backed by sqlite. I want to use the test interface from the library on the implementation in the application. Like this

```kotlin
class TreeDB:BinaryTree<Int,String>(){...}
```

In the tests in the application

```kotlin
class TreeDBTests:TreeTests<Int,String> {
   override val tree = TreeDB()
}
```

And then all the tests written for a possible implemention of BinaryTree are run on the TreeDB class.

However, code written in the tests of a library are not exported to consumers of the library. Anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to treat test utils as just any other library that serves a purpose. If, as it seems to be in your case, those test utils are also required for testing the original lib, you will have to separate interface and implementation from the original lib, e.g.

```
bintree-interface <– bintree-testutils (TreeTests etc.)
                ^– bintree-implementation
```

Now the tests for `bintree-implementation` can use `TreeTests` and your tests for `TreeDB` can as well.

Comment: thanks. I seems a little silly to me to have a library that is just an interface, but I guess I am learning architecture and design the hard way. Although if you know any good reading material on the sort information related software design like my question I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The single interface can be the seed of more. Or you realise that everything can be a monolith and unite it in a single module. Sometimes you have to try one thing to see that the other option is better.